# How do I fix “swap area creation failed” error

Tags: command-line, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I have a brand new ~465GiB SSD that I am trying to partition for Ubuntu 18.04.3.

I may have made the mistake of turning it into a startup disk using the startup disk creation tool.

I have since had trouble installing Ubuntu on it. To try to fix the issue, I created an installation USB stick and I was able to successfully boot into it and can see the SSD on the system.

Following instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/862677),
I was able to successfully partition the SSD into an EFI(255MiB), swap(12GiB) and /root(rest of space) during the 5th part of the installation process. (My ram is 8GiB)

However, whenever I click “install now” I always get a “Failed to create swap area on partition #x.” The are no other devices connect to the system so installer only sees the SSD.

I ran these two commands in terminal;
[image: commands]

And the SSDs mountpoint is listed as `/cdrom`

Could this be what’s causing the swap creation failure in the installer? 
If it is, how can I fix it? 
If it isn’t what commands can I run to troubleshoot this issue?

NB: I do not have a CD-ROM with Ubuntu on it. I’ve only got the USB stick.

Thanks.

Comment: obviously you made mistakes when you partitioned the drive and you don't need that big swap, read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: With a smallish 500G SSD, don't manually partition the drive, let the Ubuntu installer do it. Lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive) and reinstall Ubuntu. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I wiped the drive and reinstalled Ubuntu with 1 issue; grub could not be installed but I was able to manually install it later on and reboot into the SSD with no issues. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Using the live USB I unmounted, and edited the SSD via the Disks tool; resetting it to its default state, then rebooted and reinstalled Ubuntu with no issues. 
I didn’t have to manually partition the drive like before.

Thanks @heynnema